# Find the steady state temperature of the rod

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A rod occupying the interval $0 \leq x \leq l$ is subject to the heat source

$f(x) =0, $ for $ 0 < x < L/2$,
$f(x) =H $ for $  L/2 <x <L ,H>0$

(1)The rod satisﬁes the heat equation $$u_t = u_{xx} + f(x)$$ and its ends are kept at zero temperature. Find the steady-state temperature of the rod. 
(2)Which point is the hottest, and what is the temperature there?

Attempt: I only know that since, its ends are kept at zero temperature, $$u_t=0$$. Where should I go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the steady state, you are solving

$$u_t=0 \implies u_{xx}=-f(x)$$

The general solution to this, given $f$, is pretty straightforward:

$$u(x) = \begin{cases} c_1 x+c_2 & x \in \left (0,\frac{L}{2}\right)\\-\frac12 H x^2 + d_1 x+d_2 & x \in \left (\frac{L}{2},L\right) \end{cases} $$

Yes, we have different constants in each branch of the integration interval.  We thus need four conditions.  Two come from the boundary conditions:

$$u(0)=u(L)=0$$

The other two come from continuity requirements for $u$ and its derivative (otherwise, the heat flow is discontinuous, not what should happen in a steady-state solution).  Thus,

$$c_1 \frac{L}{2}+c_2 = -\frac18 H L^2 + d_1 \frac{L}{2} + d_2$$

$$c_1 = -\frac12 H L + d_1$$

Four equations, four unknowns, solve.  It's not as bad as you may think.  For example, $c_2=0$.  The rest fall out from simple substitutions.  The result I get is

$$u(x) = \begin{cases} \frac18 H L x & x \in \left (0,\frac{L}{2}\right)\\-\frac12 H x^2 + \frac{5}{8} H L x-\frac18 H L^2 & x \in \left (\frac{L}{2},L\right) \end{cases} $$

**EDIT**

To see what the above temperature looks like, rewrite the above result in the following form:

$$f(y) = y \,\theta \left ( \frac12-y\right) - (4 y-1)(y-1)\, \theta \left (y- \frac12\right) $$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function, $y=x/L$, and $f(y) = 8 u(L y)/(H L^2)$.

Here is a plot of $f(y)$:

[image]

Comment: How should I know that the **derivative** is continuous at steady state?Is it a property of steady state

Comment: "otherwise, the heat flow is discontinuous, not what should happen in a steady-state solution"

Comment: So if the function is continuous,then does the derivative also become continuous

Comment: Also at steady state does that mean that at a **particular time**, the temperature at two distinct points are the same.

Comment: @clarkson: I think you are misunderstanding.  It's the physics that demands continuity of the derivative.  No, continuous functions do not necessarily have continuous derivatives (e.g., $|x|$).  But the physics only makes sense when we impose that condition.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the explanation