# Heat equation form $u_t = u_{xx} + f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

What is the Heat equation form $u_t = u_{xx} + f(x)$.What is this $f(x)$ means.
In the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503716/find-the-steady-state-temperature-of-the-rod) it is used.

(That is it hasn't asked to change $u_t = \alpha^2 u_{xx}$ as $ u_t = u_{xx} + f(x)$) but as in that link f(x) range of values are  given.In that case can I add f(x) to the heat equation $u_t = \alpha^2 u_{xx}$ and solve the problem in a similar way.
What is the role of f(x) here and in the derivation of heat equation how does it appear?

Comment: [Internal heat generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Internal_heat_generation)

Comment: Mathematically, it makes your PDE non-homogeneous.  One way to solve it is to find a particular steady-state solution of the non-homogeneous equation (disregarding initial  condition), then solve the homogeneous equation with appropriate initial/boundary conditions,
and add the two solutions.